# MySQL Querying for 2 values in same column that have the same 3rd value and returning counts

Tags: mysql

I am trying to construct a query for usage logs that counts the number of times two packages are used concurrently for an uploadID.  In other words, I want to know how many times 2 packages appear for each uploadID.  Here is a sample of the table I have data stored in MySQL.

```
uploadID  package  
1         value1
1         value2
1         value3

2         value2
2         value3
2         value4

3         value1
3         value3
3         value4

4         value1
4         value3
4         value4
```

The output I am looking for would be something like this:

```
Concurrent Packages    Count
value1 & value2          1
value1 & value3          3
value1 & value4          2
value2 & value3          2
value2 & value4          1  
value3 & value4          3
```

I have tried a number of queries to achieve this, but nothing seems to work.  Ideally, I would like to put the output in a matrix as follows once I get the counts:

```
        value1  value2  value3  value4
value1    -       1       3       2
value2    1       -       2       1     
value3    3       2       -       3
value4    2       1       3       -
```

I would really appreciate any suggestions as to how to achieve this.  The data is being stored in a MySQL database but the final matrix will be rendered in a PHP web application.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Keeping it simple with the first version, this should do what you want;

```
SELECT CONCAT(a.package, ' & ', b.package) "Concurrent Packages",
       COUNT(*) "Count"
FROM packages a
CROSS JOIN packages b
WHERE a.package<b.package AND a.uploadid=b.uploadid
GROUP BY a.package,b.package
ORDER BY a.package,b.package
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5bef1/19).

As for the second version, it *can* be done with MySQL, but the solution gets quite a bit more complex. If you want to make an attempt, there is [info here](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#523) that will get you started.

Short explanation of the query; the `CROSS JOIN` between the table and itself will return all combinations of rows. We filter out so that we only count the ones where the values are alphabetical and the uploadid matches in the `WHERE` (the alphabetical is just to avoid that `a matching b` and `b matching a` count as two separate matches). After that, we `COUNT` the number of rows, `GROUP BY` the values so we get a count per combination.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!!! I had been working on this for days and was really stuck.  I am very grateful!